# Firefox master password generates random popups asking for the password

Tags: firefox, password-management, password-protection

I am using a master password to keep my data safe in Firefox. However, it quite annoyingly ask me to provide the master password at random times. If I don't provide it, just press <kbd>Escape</kbd> nothing happens, just delays the dialog window saying:

> Please enter the master password for the Software Security Device

I wonder what is the point of this? Even if I only have a single window playing music from youtube it sometimes stops the music to ask for the master password, generating a popup on the workspace I am currently on, which I tend not even to notice, so later I have to actively search for it just to tell it I am not currently on a login form so I won't provide my password.

Can I somehow set up Firefox that I only have to enter my master password when it actually is required for the current page?